# as slow as it is?

Tags: meaning

I came across the following sentence.

> I'm in my heavy tank. as slow as it is, I'm bringing it to the front line to help my team.

Here are two questions.

First, Can you explain "as slow as it is" more easily to me?  I guess that the original form is like "As the tank is slow as it is,". Right?

Second, I can't get the meaning of 'bringing'. please explain detailed or with alternate words.

Comment: *as ... as = equally*; *I'm bringing it* means your moving yourself along with the tank to some place.

Comment: @Ustanak Yeah, Thanks to you and Peter, I got to have the grasp of the word 'bring' in its usage. I've mistaken that 'bring' can be used when the speaker is at destination. but I found the present progressive like 'i'm bringing'  in my sentence above is used. so I think it make a little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction

> **as** *adjective* **as it is**

is used to **emphasize** the properties of the adjective used, meaning **very + adjective**

> **as slow as it is**  *(very slow)*
>   **as expensive as it is**  *(very expensive)*
>   **as complicated as it is**  *(very complicated)*
>   **as tall as he is** *(very tall)*
>   **as pretty as she is** *(very pretty)*

and is used to make a counterfactual statement

> As tall as he is, he doesn't play basketball
>   As pretty as she is, she doesn't have a boyfriend

The use of **bring** in your example means **to lead** or **to drive** or **to get**.
It does not mean **to carry**.

> **Bring** the horses around.
>   I didn't want to **bring up** the uncomfortable subject.

Comment: Thank you Peter. but I can't understand your exaplanation and example sentences on a counterfactual statement, because in my guess my sentence can break up like 'the tank is slow, but I bring it to the front line.'.  or 'Though the tank is slow, I bring it to the front line.' by context meaning.

Comment: I don't think it is a counterfactual exactly; it just means "regardless of this fact" or "although".  So your guess is correct, @GTKim; it means something like "I'm in my heavy tank even though it is slow" or "I'm in my heavy tank despite the fact that it is slow."